# Error on inserting values to SQLite DB ?Can anyone solve this?

Tags: android, sqlite

Below is the DB coding   for  creating Table Visitors to store name and adress  of place

public class DbFav {

```
/** for database */
static final String DataBaseName = "Favdb";

 /** for register table */
static final String favtable = "Visiters";
static final String VisitID = "visitid";


 static   final  String ColNam="Name";

static   final  String ColAdd="Address";


public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;


private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE ="Create table " + favtable + "("+VisitID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ColNam+ " VARCHAR(15)," + ColAdd+ " VARCHAR(15)) ";
private final Context context;  //for  the  linkage  of  the  database  wid  the  app
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DbFav(Context ctx){
    Log.i("test****", "**test***");
    this.context = ctx;   
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){

        //super(context, DataBaseName , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        super(context, DataBaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.i("context","context");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE);
        //db.execSQL(SEARCH_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.i("************", "table created");
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { //for update
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("tag", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "+ newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + favtable);

        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DbFav open() throws SQLException{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i("open", "message");
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}


public long insert(String Name,String Address ) {
    Log.i("**** suruchitest **** ","*** test ***");

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();


    initialValues.put(ColNam,Name); //key , value
    initialValues.put(ColAdd,Address);
    Log.i("Values Inserted","Values are inserted");
    return db.insert(favtable, null, initialValues);
```

Values  to be  saved  to the DB from below  coding which  gives the  exception  of Visitors  contain  no Col named (Name, Address)

```
get_place=trname.getText().toString();
get_add=tradd.getText().toString();
db.open();
db.insert(get_place,get_add);
db.close();
```

> ```
> Error inserting Name=KT Royal Hotel Sangrur Address=Nankiana Chowk, Patiala Bypass Road, Sangrur, Punjab 148001, India
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
> ```

Comment: please put your logcat error here ......

Comment: I'm not sure if varchar is a data type in android SQLite.

Comment: @allancth varchar is a datatype . Without logcat erre it is difficult to find out error.

Comment: You defined `Name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` but try to insert String

Comment: @tynn, most probably! In fact, yes! Good catch.

Comment: I  edit  my ques see  above  and  here is the logacat  http://i.stack.imgur.com/FX2eb.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FX2eb.png

Comment: Error inserting Name=KT Royal Hotel Sangrur Address=Nankiana Chowk, Patiala Bypass Road, Sangrur, Punjab 148001, India
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states

> [INSERT INTO Visiters(Name,Address) VALUES (?,?)] datatype mismatch

You've defined `Name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` to be an integer and try to insert a string into the table.

```
public long insert(String Name,String Address) {
    [...]
    initialValues.put(ColNam,Name); // Name should be an int
    [...]
}
```

You need to define your table correctly.

**Note:** don't forget to delete your data for testing after you've made changes to the SQL scheme.

Also you should use [`TEXT`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) instead of `VARCHAR(15)`.

> SQLite does not impose any length restrictions

Comment: I already  edit my   code  see  that    private static final String REGISTER_TABLE_CREATE ="Create table " + favtable + "("+VisitID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ColNam+ " VARCHAR(15)," + ColAdd+ " VARCHAR(15)) ";   for  more information  see  above the edited ques.

Comment: Error  is on therse   two lines  return       db.insert(favtable, null, initialValues);         db.insert(get_place,get_add);

Comment: yes, thanks  it works . Can  you tell me where  I see  this  inserted values ?

Comment: I don't fully get your question. You can find the values in your database file which is saved inside your private data storage.

Comment: I mean  how  i see  the inserted values in DB?